# No semisimple Lie group acting on Klein bottle

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, topological-groups

How to show that there is no semisimple Lie group can act transitively on the Klein bottle?

So in general, if $X$ is a homogeneous space of a solvable Lie group. Is it true that $X$ can't be written as a homogeneous space of a semisimple Lie group?

Comment: The answer to your general question is no. For example, the hyperbolic plane is a homogeneous space for both $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ and its subgroup of upper triangular matrices. There are many examples of this kind. Why do you think no semisimple Lie group can act transitively on the Klein bottle?

Comment: I think your question must be answered by Mostow here: https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969437?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents